# WPF button with imagebrush issues

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I would like to have image button.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DisplayProductCommand}" >
   <Button.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="test.jpg"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

By using the way above, I am facing an issue where the image doesn't cover whole button.

[image]

As shown above, this is the result and there is transparent spaces around.
Please find below the original image:

[image]

What can I do to cover the whole button?

Comment: Do you really need the image? It looks like you could recreate this in Blend quite easily.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need re-write controltemplate of button, replace default layout by removing **ButtonChrome** or you can set **BorderThickness** property of button to zero.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DisplayProductCommand}" BorderThickness="0">
   <Button.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="test.jpg"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: I don't have to do something like this to make it work, the OP's problem has something strange.

Comment: @KingKing, em..I think the original picture has invisible(shadow effect) area(right side and bottom side) which cause this problem, remove border of this button will make thing better, or talk to designer to find a better way.

Comment: em cl...looks like that fix is not really reliable.

Answer (score 0):

As @geedub mentioned, you can just define a colour gradient to match that image:

```
<Button Content="Look at my background" Padding="10,5">
    <Button.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFE5E5E5" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFBABED3" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

If this is not acceptable for your requirements then I would advise that you crop your image to remove the shadow effect that chao wang mentioned.